# Bestiary of well defined QFTs

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In trying to understand something about Quantum Field Theories and especially the mathematics behind them (or lack thereof) I have a hard time harvesting a handful of well defined examples (other than the free scalar field).

In the hope it will grant me a better understanding of what a QFT is or is not, I would kindly ask anyone knowing of some well defined examples, wheter toy models or something more involved, if they could point some references or even briefly sketch some constructions.

Comment: I don't if that's what you are after but you can find some examples in this previous answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27569/which-qfts-were-rigorously-constructed/27574#27574

Comment: That's, that's it. I looked for a question like that for so long, but somewhat it escaped me. Thank you so much.